# Singleton method not getting called in Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am calling a Singleton method that does not get called when I try doing this. 
I get no errors or anything, just that I am unable to see the CCLOG message.

Under what reasons would a compiler not give you error and not allow you to call a method?

```
[[GameManager sharedGameManager] openSiteWithLinkType:kLinkTypeDeveloperSite];
```

The method is defined as follows:

```
-(void)openSiteWithLinkType:(LinkTypes)linkTypeToOpen
{

    CCLOG(@"WE ARE IN openSiteWithLinkType"); //I NEVER SEE THIS MESSAGE

    NSURL *urlToOpen = nil;

    if (linkTypeToOpen == kLinkTypeDeveloperSite) 
    {
        urlToOpen = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somesite.com"];    
    }

    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:urlToOpen])
    {
         CCLOG(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[urlToOpen description]);
        [self runSceneWithID:kMainMenuScene];
    }

}
```

HERE IS THE CODE TO MY SINGLETON:

```
#import "GameManager.h"
#import "MainMenuScene.h"


@implementation GameManager
static  GameManager* _sharedGameManager = nil;
@synthesize isMusicON;
@synthesize isSoundEffectsON;
@synthesize hasPlayerDied;

+(GameManager*) sharedGameManager
{
@synchronized([GameManager class])
    {

        if (!_sharedGameManager) 
        {
            [[self alloc] init];
            return _sharedGameManager;
        }
        return nil;
    }

}


+(id)alloc
{

    @synchronized ([GameManager class])
    {
        NSAssert(_sharedGameManager == nil,@"Attempted to allocate a second instance of the Game Manager singleton");
        _sharedGameManager = [super alloc];
        return _sharedGameManager;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        //Game Manager initialized
        CCLOG(@"Game Manager Singleton, init");
        isMusicON = YES;
        isSoundEffectsON = YES;
        hasPlayerDied = NO;
        currentScene = kNoSceneUninitialized;
    }

    return self;

}


-(void) runSceneWithID:(SceneTypes)sceneID
{
    SceneTypes oldScene = currentScene;
    currentScene = sceneID;
    id sceneToRun = nil;


    switch (sceneID) 
    {
        case kMainMenuScene:
            sceneToRun = [MainMenuScene node];
            break;

        default:
            CCLOG(@"Unknown Scene ID, cannot switch scenes");
            return;
            break;
    }

    if (sceneToRun == nil)
    {

        //Revert back, since no new scene was found
        currentScene = oldScene;
        return;
    }




    //Menu Scenes have a value of < 100
    if (sceneID < 100) 
    {
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSizeInPixels;
            if (screenSize.width == 960.0f)
            {
                //iPhone 4 retina
                [sceneToRun setScaleX:0.9375f];
                [sceneToRun setScaleY:0.8333f];
                CCLOG(@"GM: Scaling for iPhone 4 (retina)");
            }
            else
            {
                [sceneToRun setScaleX:0.4688f];
                [sceneToRun setScaleY:0.4166f];
                CCLOG(@"GM: Scaling for iPhone 3G or older (non-retina)");
            }

        }    

    }


    if ([[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] == nil)
    {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:sceneToRun];
    }
    else

    {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:sceneToRun];

    }

}


-(void)openSiteWithLinkType:(LinkTypes)linkTypeToOpen
{

    CCLOG(@"WE ARE IN openSiteWithLinkType");

    NSURL *urlToOpen = nil;

    if (linkTypeToOpen == kLinkTypeDeveloperSite) 
    {
        urlToOpen = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somesite.com"];    
    }

    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:urlToOpen])
    {
         CCLOG(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[urlToOpen description]);
        [self runSceneWithID:kMainMenuScene];
    }

}


-(void) test
{


    CCLOG(@"this is test");

}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps sharedGameManager is returning nil? This won't cause an error.

Edit: The issue is in the new code you posted:

```
if (!_sharedGameManager) {
    [[self alloc] init];
    return _sharedGameManager;
}
return nil;
```

If `_sharedGameManager` is non-nil, this will return nil. You want:

```
if (!_sharedGameManager) {
    [[self alloc] init];
}
return _sharedGameManager;
```

Comment: How would one test if a SIngleton returns nil?

Comment: You can log the result of [GameManager sharedGameManager] and see if it is nil. Perhaps you could post the code for sharedGameManager?

Comment: Don't use logging, leave that to scripting languages where you don't have a debugger. Set a breakpoint instead. Here's my guide for debugging with Xcode: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/10/xcode-4-debugging-crashcourse/

Comment: Thank You. That was indeed the issue. I replaced the code with: +(GameManager*)sharedGameManager {
    @synchronized([GameManager class])                             // 2
    {
        if(!_sharedGameManager)                                    // 3
            [[self alloc] init]; 
        return _sharedGameManager;                                 // 4
    }
    return nil; 
}

Answer (score 1):

Check [this Cocoa With Love article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) on how to make a proper singleton.